# What is the consequence of ignoring the warning:unchecked conversion in java

Tags: java, generics, unchecked-conversion

I know why I am getting the warning(i.e assigning raw type to parameterized type), but I don't exactly get what will be possible sequences if I ignore the warning.

```
List list = new ArrayList();           
List<Integer> iList = list;     // warning: unchecked conversion
```

Comment: Have you seen [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: @khelwood no, thanks so useful.

Comment: Why would you ignore the warning when it's a simple fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (only) runtime consequence is code failing due to `ClassCastException`'s, either directly or indirectly<sup>1</sup>.

The other consequence is that you allow errors that *should* be detected and corrected at compile time to proceed into test, and maybe production where the costs and consequences may be significantly worse.

While ignoring these warnings is a bad idea, suppressing them incorrectly can be worse.

> what do you mean by suppressing them incorrectly ?

I mean adding a `@SuppressWarning` annotation for a warning that actually will result in a runtime exception or another (real) problem.   Adding a `@SuppressWarning` annotation just to make the compiler "shut up" is a dangerous habit.

---

<sup>1 - For instance, if you caught and incorrectly squashed a `ClassCastException`!</sup>

Comment: what do you mean by *suppressing them incorrectly* ?

Answer (score 2):

You get `ClassCastException` at runtime. Casts generated by the compiler could fail at runtime. This will violate the fundamental guarantee provided by the generic type system. Literally your code is not type safe. Check this out.

```
List list = new ArrayList();           
List<Integer> iList = list;
list.add("wrong");
for (Integer integer : iList) {
    System.out.println(integer);
}
```

Here's the error you get at runtime.

`java.lang.String` cannot be cast to `java.lang.Integer`

Comment: are there other possible consequence or this `ClassCastException` only?

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the warning may result in `ClassCastException` if you expect the `List` to contain elements of one type and it contains elements of an unrelated type.

For example, the following will pass compilation (with a warning) and will throw `ClassCastException` in runtime:

```
List list = new ArrayList();    
list.add("something");       
List<Integer> iList = list;
Integer i = iList.get(0);
```

Comment: are there other possible consequence or this `ClassCastException` only?

Comment: @TheScientificMethod I believe that's it. It's a serious consequence.